# Creating a generic method which detects and handles various types

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to accomplish something like the following, but apparently it's not clear to me how to create a generic method, well, generically:

```
public static string DecNHex<T>(T val)
{
    if (val.GetType() is System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef)
    {
        return "{ " + val.Handle.ToString() + " / " + val.Handle.ToString("x") + "}";
    }
    else
    {
        return "{ " + val.ToString() + " / " + val.ToString("x") + " }";
    }
}
```

Issues:

1. The compiler says the `if (val.GetType() is X)` comparison will never evaluate as true.
2. The compiler won't allow the second return statement, because in `val.ToString("x")` there is no overload of ToString() that takes one parameter.

I understand why it's complaining.  How do I get around these issues?  Also: am I not going to be able to handle this 'generically' ?  Am I going to have to write an `if` statement for every type? If so, I clearly don't understand the benefits of a 'generic' method.

Comment: Well in this case writing an overloaded method will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Should be `if (val is X)`, not `if (val.GetType() is X)`. The expression `Y is X` is true if and only if `Y` is an instance of `X`. `val.GetType()` is an instance of the `Type` class, which is never an instance of `System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef`.
2. Without any generic constraints, all the compiler knows is that `T` inherits `Object`. So there is only one `ToString` method overload on `T val`, and it takes no parameters.

C# does not support language-level generics specialization (like C++ template specialization). You can construct, for example, a `Dictionary<Type, Action> dict` and then do something like `dict[x.GetType()](x)`, but the specifics aren't clear in your question, so I can't do that for you.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason my pre-ask search did not turn up the same quality of questions as the "related" side tab did AFTER I asked my question, and I can see by reading through those that I can't easily create the method I need.  Looks like I'll just write a bunch of type specific overloads.  Thanks!

Comment: For those looking for a specific solution to what Timothy describes in point 1, You can either say

`a is sbyte`

or say

`a.GetType() == typeof(sbyte)`

Comment: @ForenzikBlatt For `sbyte` that will work, but in general that's not necessarily true.  The expression `obj.GetType() == typeof( T )` means that the type of `obj` must *identically* be `T`.  Whereas `obj is T` only means that `obj` is convertible to type `T` (ignoring user-defined conversions).  So, if `obj` derives from (or implements) `T`, then `obj is T` will evaluate to true.